# Cant send request without undefined or 400 response code

Tags: javascript, post, discord, request, webhooks

**Issue:**
I am trying to get data, then send it through a discord webhook. The webhook sends before the request can fully get the data it needs therefor returning `undefined`. So I tried to put it in a timeout function with a 100ms delay to give the data some time to collect. When doing this I now get a 400 response code. How can this be fixed?

**Code:**

```
$.getJSON('link that returns data in json', (data) => {
    info = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
});

setTimeout(() => {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "discord webhook link")

    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    
    const params = {
        username: "Info",
        avatar_url: "",
        content: `${info}`
    }

    request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
}, 100);
```

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT:**
I know a timeout function works to help the data load then get it because I tested it with `console.log();`. It just throws the 400 response when I try doing it with the request in the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by realizing there was a characterization limit on discords webhook content, so I split it into 2 requests and sent half and half.